# How to get a system nouveau-free

Tags: 12.04, nouveau

nouveau is giving me a hell of a lot of problems, and I would like to start without it altogether. I removed basically everything, up to libdrm-nouveau1a, because plymouth depends on it and if I try to remove plymouth, the whole system goes with it.

How can I obtain a system completely free from nouveau ? is it even possible ?

Version is Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can blacklist the driver like this:
`echo "blacklist nouveau" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`
I suggest installing your nvidia driver before rebooting after doing that

Comment: I would also like to remove all the xorg stuff referencing nouveau. I assume that if you don't have the kernel module, they won't work, but I am trying to be really clean, because the behavior is really weird

Comment: if you blacklist it, it will not load even if it is installed

Comment: I you want to remove all the "xorg stuff" that is going to be more difficult. Now you are starting to talk about building from source code. If you want to get that low level, IMO, use Gentoo.

Answer (score 0):

You need a video card driver, if you don't use nouveau then X probably won't even start. To stop using nouveau you need to use the Nvidia drivers.

Comment: can't I use a basic VESA until I install nvidia ?